# SPFx remove provisioned lists on uninstall?

Tags: spfx, provisioning

Say I have an SPFX app that provisions a list, then user uninstalls the app.  The list remains.  Is there any way to remove provisioned assets on uninstall of an app?
*Pnp.powershell not an option unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. SPFx does not provide a mechanism for you to run code on app uninstall. The only option is to run an external job, perhaps on a timer, that checks for sites that have the list but don't have the app installed.

Comment: Thanks again! It makes sense.